Simplifying Riccati differential equation with substitution. Is the textbook wrong?
Dear smart math people,
I am reading a textbook on electrocatalysis and trying to follow a derivation, but for the life of me, I cannot seem to get the same result as the author.  Here's the problem:
Based on some chemical reactions that I won't bore you with, we get the following Riccati differential equation:
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}+\frac{K}{\sigma}\theta+\frac{L}{\sigma}\theta^2+\frac{M}{\sigma}=0\qquad[1]$$
Where $\theta$ is a function of time and $K,L,M,$ and $\sigma$ are assumed to be independent of time because of chemistry reasons.
Now, the author claims that the Riccati equation above can be reduced to the below second order differential equation using the substitution $\theta=-\frac{h'\sigma}{hL}$.
$$h''-[1+\frac{K}{\sigma}]h'+\frac{LM}{\sigma^2}h=0\qquad[2]$$
Where $h'$ and $h''$ are the first and second derivatives of the change of variable $h$ with respect to time, and all other symbols have their prior meanings.
I have not been able to reproduce the author's substitution to yield [2].  I am hoping that it is because of a mathematical error that I am making and not a mistake on the author's part.
Any help is much appreciated.
Sincerely,
A Confused PhD Student

You'll need to show your working in order for us to be able to evaluate where the issue lies. Just note that the substitution $\theta \propto - h'/h$ is exactly what is in the Wikipedia page for the Riccati DE.

Okay, will do.  Thank you for the advice; I am a first time contributor, so I am still learning!  Also, thank you for the heads up about the wikipedia article using that substitution.  Not sure how I missed that.  I will take a look at that and edit the post with my work if I am still having trouble.  Thank you @Matthew Cassell!
